# Safest way to retrieve values from Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to know, what is the safest way to get `values` from Firebase Database? I ask this because I get `nil`s all over the place and it is impossible to track them. For example if I take this piece of code, how you should do it?

And for example if user somehow accessed into app while he is offline, I am getting `nil`s and crashes.

Like this, I register user and add values into Firebase Database:

```
guard let username = usernameField.text, let email = emailField.text, let password = passwordField.text else{
            print("Successfully registered")
            return
        }
        if connectedToNetwork() == true{
        if passwordField.text == confirmPasswordField.text{
        FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user: FIRUser?, error) in

            if error != nil{
                print(error)
                return
            }
            guard let uid = user?.uid else{
                return
            }
            let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser

            user?.sendEmailVerification() { error in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                } else {
                    print("Email has been sent to you!")
                }
            }
            //Successfully authenticated user
            let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(fromURL: "https://snuspedia.firebaseio.com/")
            let usersReference = ref.child("users").child(uid)
            let reputation: Int  = 0
            let values = ["username": username, "email": email, "reputation": reputation] as [String : Any]// These are the values in Firebase database json tree which I get in next code part.
            usersReference.updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: {
                (err, ref) in

                if err != nil{
                    print(err)
                    return
                }
                print("User saved and logged in")
                let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main",bundle:nil)

                let ProfileViewController: UIViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileViewController")

                //Send the user to the LoginViewController
                self.present(ProfileViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            })
        })
        }else{
            let view: MessageView
            var config = SwiftMessages.Config()
            view = MessageView.viewFromNib(layout: .StatusLine)
            view.configureTheme(.error)
            config.presentationStyle = .top
            config.presentationContext = .window(windowLevel: UIWindowLevelStatusBar)


            view.configureContent(title: nil, body: "Passwords do not match!", iconImage: nil, iconText: nil, buttonImage: nil, buttonTitle: "Hide", buttonTapHandler: { _ in SwiftMessages.hide() })

            SwiftMessages.show(config: config, view: view)
        }
        }else{
            let view: MessageView
            var config = SwiftMessages.Config()
            view = MessageView.viewFromNib(layout: .StatusLine)
            view.configureTheme(.error)
            config.presentationStyle = .top
            config.presentationContext = .window(windowLevel: UIWindowLevelStatusBar)


            view.configureContent(title: nil, body: "The internet connection appears to be offline.", iconImage: nil, iconText: nil, buttonImage: nil, buttonTitle: "Hide", buttonTapHandler: { _ in SwiftMessages.hide() })

            SwiftMessages.show(config: config, view: view)
        }
```

And like this, I try to get user username and reputation and profile image:

```
self.loggedInUser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
        //get the logged in users details
        self.databaseRef.child("users").child(self.loggedInUser!.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in
            //store the logged in users details into the variable
            print(self.loggedInUser)
            let snapshot = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
            self.usernameLabel.text = snapshot["username"] as! String
            if let reputation = snapshot["reputation"] {
                self.reputationLabel.text = "\(reputation)"
            } else {
                print("reputation is nil")
            }
            if(snapshot["profileImage"] !== nil)
            {
                let databaseProfilePic = snapshot["profileImage"]
                    as! String

                let data = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(string: databaseProfilePic)!)

                self.setProfilePicture(self.profileImageView,imageToSet:UIImage(data:data!)!)
            }

            self.loadingIndicator.stopAnimating()
        }
```

For example, in the last code, every time I go to the view, it loads the data again even if I have **enabled** the `persistence` in `appDelegate`.

For me, it seems that I am doing everything wrong because every `print()` I do (which is not right to debug I know) outputs Optionals.

How do I get rid of them? Every tip is highly valued. Should I store some of the values into `userDefaults` to prevent some errors? Or should I use OOP and make struct for user?

I gotta say that I've read so much about them but can't find a good answer.

Comment: I understand that it's frustrating that your app crashes But it'll be hard to help without knowing what specific place in your code is getting a nil. In general you'll get the best results if you [reproduce the problem from scratch in a minimal app](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and share that here.

Comment: I didn't asked to point nils. I wanted to know, how to get rid of optionals and what is the best way to get data from Firebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the above code is meant to run when the user first logs into your app, then I'd highly recommend you store their info; your object that is, into `Defaults`. You simply would have to conform your class to `NSCoding` and implement its protocols. This would speed up your launch since you would just have to make one async call; for image retrieval, in contrast to two.

You'd have to manually update these values though which could easily be done in either `func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication)` or `func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication)`

**It's not advisable to store images into `Defaults` so I'd recommend you store the URL then simply download the image.**

**Edit:
I'd also recommend you implement your `User` as a singleton so as any changes made are applied throughout your app hence making it easier to maintain. More info on this is found [here](http://krakendev.io/blog/the-right-way-to-write-a-singleton)**

For the case that it's not, then this is how I'd implement the second portion

```
func online()
{
    guard let user =  FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser else
    {
        print("User not FrB logged In")
        return
    }
    //Have you implemented an = operator in your class? Correct me if I'm wrong but this may be doing a shallow copy instead of assigning the variables respectively. If you haven't then I'd recommend you implement a copy constructor to perform a deep copy
    self.loggedUser = user

    //get the logged in users details
    self.databaseRef.child("users").child(user.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in
        //store the logged in users details into the variable
        print(self.loggedInUser)

        guard let snapshot = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject], let userName = snapshot["username"] as? String, let reputation = snapshot["reputation"] as? String, let profilePicURL = snapshot["profileImage"] as? String
        else
        {
            print("Error with FrB snapshot")
            return
        }

        self.usernameLabel.text = userName
        self.reputationLabel.text = reputation

        let imageURL: URL = URL(string: profilePicURL)! // safe to unwrap here since we know it has a value

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: imageURL, completionHandler: { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

            guard let sessionData = data, error == nil else
            {
                print("Image download error")
                print(error!.localizedDescription) // safe to unwrap because we know error!=nil
                return
            }

            // If not performed in the background, it'll block the UI and your app may be terminated if the operation takes a while
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.profileImage = UIImage(data: sessionData)!
                self.loadingIndicator.stopAnimating() // stop animating after retrieving the image
            })

        }).resume()
    }
}
```

I'm certain you can refractor the other method. Cheers mate!

Comment: First of all. Thank you for detailed answer. But I have some questions, how could you assign value of type `UIImage` to type  `UIImageView` ?

Secondly, I like the way you do this safely. Like this I do not get crash at least if something is nil etc.. But.. The output is for some reason "Error with FrB snapshot" but I am sure that those values exists in database.

Comment: No problem buddy..You can assign images by doing `yourImageView.image = yourImage`. Second, `FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser` checks if their is a token for a user that logged into your app. Its failing because that token doesn't exist in your phone. After creating the user, you need to `FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail:)` the user. This way a token will be stored in your app with which you can use to check for exists later on. And once you sign them out by doing `try! FIRAuth.auth()?.signOut()`, then that token is reverted back to `nil`

Comment: But it exists. I do sign in and I tried to output the token and it printed it.

Comment: How are you getting the token? Are you using `FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.getTokenWithCompletion`

Comment: No, just make variable: `var loggedInUser:AnyObject?` and then `self.loggedInUser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser`. This is when I register and make segue to profile view. But if login then just signIn(withEmal)

Comment: Try breaking down the guard statement to

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125005/discussion-between-tarvo-maesepp-and-emil-david).